# navigate to previous page when doing a validation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, lifecycle

Using Flutter's lifecycle methods, I would like to do a validation before displaying the page, if the validation is true it stays on the page, if the validation is false it should go back one page.

**How can I do this?**

I have a method below that will return true or false, I need to call this method before displaying the page to check if it will continue on the page or if it should rewind the page.

```
  Future<bool> getOrderPendingExist() async {
    TripLocation? tripLocation = this._tripLocationDetails.value;
    List<Order>? orders = [];
    orders = tripLocation?.orders;
    Iterable<Order> ordersPending = orders!.where((order) => order.status != "success");
    return ordersPending.length == 0 ? false : true;
  }
```

This method above I would like to call before rendering the page, I believe that with Flutter's lifecycle methods I can do this, and validate if it will stay on the page or if it will go back one page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

In `initState`:

```
getOrderPendingExist().then((valid) {
  if (!valid) Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```

Comment: I tried to execute an asynchronous function inside the initState but I got the following error: _TripLocationDetailsScreenState.initState() returned a Future.

Comment: Right, I edited my answer.